# how to handle ajax failure, when one ajax of multiple nested calls fails; using $.when method

Tags: jquery

I am having multiple ajax requests, which i want to execute sequentially, so i am nesting them using $.when jQuery method.

```
$.when(
  $.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType : 'json'
   }),
  $.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType : 'json'
  }),
 $.ajax({
   url : url,
   type: 'GET',
   dataType : 'json'
})

).then(doThis);
```

Now the question is, i have 2nd ajax failing, which breaks everything.

i want to know, how can we continue the sequence, even when any of the call fails.

Comment: "multiple ajax requests, which i want to execute sequentially, so i am nesting them using $.when jQuery method" makes no sense. `.when()` does not give that behaviour.

Comment: do you want all three requests to start right away? or do you want to start the second one only when the first is finished?

Comment: `$.ajax` fires the request immediately

Comment: i want to start only when first is finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `when().then()` concept only works if everything in the `when()` portion is successful.  If you want to execute your AJAX calls one after the other, you would need to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    error: function() { alert("Error in call #1") },
    complete: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType : 'json',
            error: function() { alert("Error in call #2") },
            complete: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url : url,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType : 'json'
                    error: function() { alert("Error in call #3") },
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

EDIT: I updated my answer above to include a way to handle a failure of an AJAX call, using the `error` callback.

Comment: lol... Not pretty, I know.  I just wanted to show the concept.  It would probably have to be "clean-up" a little in a real world scenario. :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But i want to know, how to handle when one of the ajax call fails?

Comment: In your question you state: "i want to know, how can we continue the sequence, even when any of the call fails." So which one do you want? Continue even when one fails or handling a failure?

Comment: @devang, because this example uses the `complete` event, the sequence continues whether the requests succeed or fail. If you want to have something special happen when one fails, specify an `error` callback function.

Comment: sorry steve, if i am not clear. i want to continue even when one fails, and display error for the corresponding failed event.

Comment: This is synchronous... he wanted ASYNCHRONOUS